# How to get .ipa file with PhoneGap for iOS?

Tags: ios, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have developed an PhoneGap application using Sencha Touch 2 in Android. Now I want to develop the same in iOS without changing the code. I tried using PhoneGap Build but it was asking for Apple developer registration or developing Xcode using MacBook. Is there any other way that I can generate an .ipa file using Windows XP, PhoneGap?

Answer (score 3):

If your app really is just a straight PhoneGap app -- all HTML, JavaScript, etc. and no custom Objective-C stuff, [phonegap.com offers a build service](https://build.phonegap.com/) that'll build your app for all the platforms they support. You'll still have to register as an iOS developer and pay you $99 to get a distribution certificate, of course. According to the [iOS Build instructions](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/ios-builds) you'll need a Mac to set up your certificate and such. So realistically, you'll need to at least have *access* to a Mac from time to time, but once you've got everything set up you should be able to use the service to do your builds.

Comment: My phonegap application has no custom objective-c stuff .. I went through PhoneGap Build .. If we go for this PhoneGap Build is it still necessary for me to have a macbook or is it enough if i pay $99 and get an apple developer account ??? ... or Are both of them required ???

Comment: Almost right, but I think that no Mac is required, only a PKCS#12 key-store on your Windows computer, for which any tool such as those distributed with the JDK or ADK will work, though I use Portecle (http://portecle.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

SenchaTouch 2 incorporates directly building native Android and iPhone apps with the (still in beta) [SenchaTouch SDK Tools](http://www.sencha.com/products/sdk-tools/download) *using a Windows, Mac or Linux PC*.  I am doing this on Windows XP and 7.

After setting up your (paid) developer account with Apple, creating a developer certificate and setting up a PKCS#12 key-store<sup>(*)</sup> on your PC, you set up a packager.json targeting iOS and use:

```
> sencha app build native

[INFO] Deploying your application to <your-app-path-here>\build\package
[INFO] Copied sdk/sencha-touch.js
[INFO] Copied app.js
[INFO] Copied resources/css/app.css
[INFO] Copied resources/images
[INFO] Copied resources/icons
[INFO] Copied resources/startup
[INFO] Resolving your application dependencies (file:///<your-app-path-here>/index.html)
[INFO] Found 236 dependencies. Concatenating all into '<your-app-path-here>\build\package\app.js'
[INFO] Processed sdk/sencha-touch.js
[INFO] Minifying sdk/sencha-touch.js
[INFO] Processed app.js
[INFO] Minifying app.js
[INFO] Minifying resources/css/app.css
[INFO] Minified sdk/sencha-touch.js
[INFO] Minified app.js
[INFO] Minified resources/css/app.css
[INFO] Generated app.json
[INFO] Embedded microloader into index.html
[INFO] Packaging your application as a native app...
[INFO] The application was successfully packaged
The application was successfully signed
To run iOS simulator you need to use Mac OS X
```

to make the iOS application (which will be output as a *folder* named *`build\MyApp.app`*).

(*) Use [Portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/) to maintain your key-store.