# PhoneGap iPhone app installer

Tags: iphone, ios, cross-platform

I'm developing a cross-platform iPhone (iOS) application using [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/).

One of my clients, who want to test it, is not living in my town, and I'd like to give him an installer so he can test the program. I've already added his phone in the Apple dev center, but I don't know how to create the installer.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have been developing a cross platform app using appcelerator and have been sharing all test builds with client using tesflight.

The method of sharing is as simple as creating an account, uploading IPA, selecting the device ID of your client so that only he/she may install it on device. So once this is done, you can either invite client to sign up and download the app or simply share a download link..

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to create IPA with PhoneGap :\

Comment: check this out.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157111/how-to-get-ipa-file-with-phonegap-for-ios